# How to edit a file from within configure.ac?

Tags: r, package, autotools

I have a configure script to set up some paths for my R package during installation. I wish to edit a file based on some conditions. Is there any way to edit a file from within the configure.ac? It would be great if the solution is provided for all operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to edit a file from within the configure.ac?

`configure.ac` is not executable, but I suppose you mean that you want the `configure` script generated from it to edit a file.  The `configure` script is a shell script, and you can cause arbitrary shell code to be included in it, more or less just by including that code at the corresponding point in `configure.ac`.

The question, then, is how you would automate editing a file with a shell script.  There is a variety of alternatives, but [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) is high on my list.  You will find it on every system that can support Autoconf `configure` scripts, because such scripts use it internally.

On the other hand, this sort of thing is one of the main activities of a `configure` script, in the form of creating files (especially makefiles, but not limited to those) from templates.  You should consider building your target file of interest from a template in this way, instead of making custom-programmed edits to a file packaged in your program distribution.  This would involve

- [setting output variables](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html) containing the chosen content for the parts of the file that need to be configured;
- [designating the target file as one for `configure` to build](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Configuration-Files.html#Configuration-Files); and
- providing the template, maybe by taking a complete example file and replacing each variable part with a reference to the appropriate `@output_variable@`.

Comment: Yes, I meant `configure`. I used a template and it worked perfectly.  Thanks